# Is this a common use of 'chime'?

Tags: meaning, american-english

In a recent NYTimes article:

> He should have recused himself completely, and have formally informed
> the entire board as well as the public about any family interest.
>
> This ***chimes*** with what some ethics experts believe. Ideally, museum
> experts say, if a work is borrowed from a family...

I've never seen this usage, and an internet search offers no help. This [closed question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334519/how-can-a-person-chime) seems similar but doesn't address this usage.

It's possible that the writer meant ***jibe***, which [M/W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jibe) defines as

> to be in accord : agree —usually used with with

but I'm inclined to give the NYTimes the benefit of the doubt. At first.

ETA:
The print version of this piece appeared in today's edition, and replaces the word ***chimes*** with the word ***accords***, so apparently they weren't fully satisfied with this. I couldn't see the author's bio, but his name is Graham Bowley, which does have a British ring to it.

Comment: Dunno how common it is, but it's definitely used.  The use seems to be metaphorically implying that the behavior "rings" in synchrony with something else.

Comment: As a British English speaker **chime** sounds more natural than **jibe**. To me **jibe** is an import from the US which came in after the second world war but **chime** is of long standing.

Comment: Yes it’s a very common usage, in British English at least.

Comment: This meaning is primarily British - https://www.lexico.com/definition/chime

Comment: FWIW, as a Brit, I've _never_ heard this usage and would expect "jibe". Could be age-related.

Comment: I thought that was pretty-much the only use of "chime" and its derivation from musical harmony clear and obvious.

"Jibe" as at merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jibe - and quite likely, other dictionaries - sounds to me like a misrepresentation of "jive".

Comment: I can't personally recall any specific usage of the word used like this; but as a American English native speaker, I can say that I immediately understood the meaning without any need to think over it - so even if it isn't frequently used this side of the pond it still makes sense to me naturally.

Comment: The author [is indeed British](https://www.linkedin.com/in/graham-bowley-242b2718).

Comment: I'm less than 20 years old British and have heard this often enough. I'd never heard "jibes" though, although I've long known its meaning from looking up "jives" vs "jibes" lol.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

***[Chime with](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chime-with)***:

> to be similar to or agree with someone else’s ideas, plans, feelings etc.
> (MacMillan Dictionary)

also ***[chime in with:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chime-in-with)***

> If one thing *chimes in with* another thing or *chimes with* it, the two things are similar or consistent with each other.
> (Collins Dictionary)

Its usage derives from music, and figuratively from early 19th century.

> ***[To chime in](https://www.etymonline.com/word/chime)*** originally was musical, "join harmoniously;" of conversation by 1838. (Etymonline)

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&content=chime%20with%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cchimes%20with%3Aeng_gb_2019%2C%20chime%20with%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cchimes%20with%3Aeng_us_2019&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchime%20with%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchimes%20with%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchime%20with%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchimes%20with%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0) shows usage of phrasal verb “chime with” increasing in the last decade especially in BrE.

It is interesting that the OED suggests that jibe may be a phonetic variant of chime:

***[Jibe (v.):](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jibe)***

> "agree, fit," 1813, gibe, of unknown origin, originally U.S. colloquial, perhaps a figurative extension of earlier jib, gybe (v.) "shift a sail or boom" (see jib). ***OED, however, suggests a phonetic variant of chime, as if meaning "to chime in with, to be in harmony."***

(Etymonline)

Comment: Because it *rings true*.

Comment: "chime" in this sense is also in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chime) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chime).

Comment: It's interesting that, according to [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chime+with%2Cjibe&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10), "jibe" has always been more common than "chimes with", though the latter has picked up ever since the 1990's.

Comment: I've heard and used *chime in with* **many** times.  But, I've never heard this usage before (34 years in Canada (Quebec), then nearly 30 in the US (New England and Texas))

Comment: Native AmE speaker, 46 years old, lived in many parts of the US.  Never heard "chimes with" used this way before

Comment: BTW "jive" is also related

Comment: @wjandrea: "Jives with" [is just a mishearing/eggcorn version](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390475/a-rare-meaning-of-the-word-to-jive) of "jibes with." I suspect that "chimes with" started life the same way, with influence from the musical overtones of "harmonizes with" and the visual parallelism of a set of [wind chimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chime).

Comment: Interesting. I've (AmE) _never once_ encountered *chime with*.

Answer (score 10):

I have never heard ***chime*** used in that context, but I find at [webster-dictionary.org](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/chime) (from Webster's 1913 Dictionary) that chime can mean:

> 2. To be in harmony; to agree; to suit; to harmonize; to correspond; to fall in with.
>    Everything chimed in with such a humor.
>    (W. Irving)

Answer (score 6):

All the references other answers are digging up seem to indicate this was historically an American usage.

Having lived for around half a Century in the US, in places including Oklahoma, Pennsylvania, Ohio, Louisiana, and Florida, I can't ever remember encountering that usage of the word. I'm also seeing a few answers here from Americans assuming it must be a foriegn usage. Not to mention the question itself, which appears to have been written by a poster from Michigan.

So no, that does not appear to be a common use of "chime" any more.

Answer (score 5):

Americans would say "jibes with", so if this was the NYT, then perhaps it was a British author. I certainly wouldn't be surprised if NYT copyeditors let British usage stand, especially if it is age-old.

Comment: Not just British, "chime" in this sense is in the American English-leaning [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chime); in fact, it's verb sense #2 (vs. much further down in the British English-leaning [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chime)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This one is bizarre to me as a well-read, well-traveled, 46 year old native AmE speaker.  I've *never* heard "chimes with" used this way, yet not only does NGrams show it as not uncommon, it shows it as MORE COMMON than "jibes with" for that last decade and a half

Comment: @Kevin Very interesting. I wonder if perhaps this is a regional usage or generational? I live in the west and wonder whether perhaps this is something you'd hear in the south or midwest. But T.E.D. suggests not, so what say you ngram?

Comment: @senortim I grew up primarily in the south. But my dad was from Chicago and my mom's side mainly lived in Arizona.  I was in the Army and lived on both the east and west coast.

Comment: @Kevin Just checked out the ngram and wow! First that "chimes with" seems only slightly less popular that "jibes with" during my lifetime, and then that massive spike around 2001. But looking at the more specific instances, it may be that things like "chimes with great beauty" or "chimes with pentatonic scales" skew the data.

Comment: @senortim - The one place this was verifiably found recently appears to be the NYTimes (per the question). The Times is the kind of publication where ... well, let's say if you told me a NYT author was using a meaning they'd just stumbled over in a dictionary and had never actually encountered in the wild (which is IMHO the only way to know you are using a term properly), I would be neither shocked nor even surprised. Particularly if said person also worked on their crosswords.

Comment: @T.E.D. Spot on. Perhaps they should read old copies of The New Yorker, pre-Tina Brown. And if I ever see a NYT crossword clue "- - - - - with" (5 spaces), I will be ready.

Answer (score 2):

As a BrE speaker, I'd see it as a little stilted, but comprehensible.

I'd interpret 'jibes' as being the exact opposite, mocking or opposing, despite the dictionary definition offered.

"Chime" would seem more appropriate where used in the sense of an interjection. My preference would be "resonate".

Comment: Your sense of 'jibe' is better conveyed by ***gibe***. In the US, *jibe*, *gibe* and *jive* are often confused.

Comment: @JimMack - Cambridge maintains they are variant spellings https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gibe No doubt there would be some confusion when spoken - especially given that the MW definition and the Oxbridge definitions seem to be direct opposites. Perhaps a word best avoided.